# ¿Se puede enviar un json por SOAP en PHP?

Tags: php, json, webservice, soap

Mi pregunta es ¿Se puede mandar un *json* por *SOAP* Nativo de *PHP*?

Presento mi caso tengo que hacer una integración con el Web Service de Correos Express. Resulta que ellos trabajan con *SOAP* y *json*. Cuando intento mandar el pedido me muestra el siguiente error en Nativo

> Fatal error: SOAP Fault: (faultcode: Sender, faultstring: looks like we got no XML document)

Según lo que entiendo el *XML* armado esta mal y es obvio yo no quiero mandar un *XML* yo quiero mandar un *json*

Lo intente con nusoap y el error este no me lo tira pero si me tira otro error

> nusoap_client: Error: HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers

Ya no se cual de los dos usar por que cualquiera de los dos me da error. Aunque creo que el nativo tiene una solución mas fácil.
(Puede que este equivocado)

Si se necesita que comparta cualquiera de las dos integración (*nusoap* y nativa). Avisadme y lo pondré.

Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema similar y me rompía la cabeza, al final encontré la solución aquí: [Arne Kröger's Blog](http://arnekroeger.blogspot.com/2011/02/php-soap-error-looks-like-we-got-no-xml.html) y consiste en eliminar todos los caracteres (incluidos los saltos de línea, espacios en blanco) que hay después del `?>`

Como dice ahí es una solución sencilla, pero no sé si será tu caso.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Fabian. Gracias por responder pero dejar el enlace solo no es calidad suficiente para una buena respuesta. Es mejor explicar el contenido del enlace en tu publicacion para asi tener aqui recogida la info. Piensa que si ese enlace se rompiera, tu respuesta perdería todo su valor. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola Fabian. He recuperado tu respuesta pero has de mejorarla epxlicando en más detalle los que cuentas brevemente. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

no se puede, *nusoap* y *soap nativo* envían al parecer solamente *XML*, de todas formas empece a usar *cURL* pero estoy teniendo un problema que no puedo descifrar cual es. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Muestro el caso

```
$header = array();
$header[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$header[] = "cache-control: no-cache";

$array = json_encode($array);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.correosexpress.com/wspsc/apiRestGrabacionEnvio/json/grabacionEnvio");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxxxx:xxxxx");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);

$Response = curl_exec($curl);
$errorNo = curl_errno($curl);

if($errorNo){
  $error = curl_error($curl);
  echo $error;
  return false;
}
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
var_dump($info);

curl_close($curl);
var_dump($Response);
```

el *$array* es el *json* que estoy intentando mandar.

la respuesta que obtengo es la siguiente

```
C:\wamp64\www\.......\newPedido.php:98:
array (size=26)
  'url' => string 'https://test.correosexpress.com/wspsc/apiRestGrabacionEnvio/json/grabacionEnvio' (length=79)
  'content_type' => null
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 184
  'request_size' => int 258
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 19
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 30.311
  'namelookup_time' => float 0.125
  'connect_time' => float 0.141
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0.203
  'size_upload' => float 1132
  'size_download' => float 0
  'speed_download' => float 0
  'speed_upload' => float 37
  'download_content_length' => float -1
  'upload_content_length' => float 1132
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.234
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
  'primary_ip' => string 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (length=14)
  'certinfo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'primary_port' => int 443
  'local_ip' => string 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (length=13)
  'local_port' => int 54054
C:\wamp64\www\......\newPedido.php:101:string '' (length=0)
```

Espero que con eso sea suficiente información para una respuesta. Muchas gracias.