# webservice soap php

Tags: php, sql, webservice, soap

Estoy haciendo un webservice con php, y ya tengo listo todo, me entrega lo que tiene que hacer. Aquí dejo mi función del service.php

Estoy usando SOAPUI para probarlo, pero me entrega la solución hacia el lado, así:

Alguien sabe alguna forma que lo imprima hacia abajo? Intente ponerle un br pero no me funciono.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.

[image: ws]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo agrega saltos de línea `\n` donde los requieras, por ejemplo: `$listado = $listado."<facturas>\n";` o `."</td>\n<td>"`.

Creo que sería mejor usar la notación [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredocn) y, aparte de tener un código más legible, también puedes poner comillas donde se debe:

```
// El identificador para este ejemplo es STR
$listado = <<<STR
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>RUTE</td>
  <td>FECHA</td>
  <td>DTE</td>
  <td>FOLIO</td>
  <td>DIRECCION</td>
  <td>MONTO</td>
</tr>
STR; // El identificador debe estar en la primera columna, seguido de ;
```

Y, lo mejor, puedes incluir variables en el código. Pero si hablamos de elementos de array o propiedades y métodos de objetos, hay que encerrarlos entre llaves `{$array['indice']}`:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // $listado .= equivale a $listado = $listado .
    $listado .= <<<STR
<facturas>
<tr>
  <td>{$row['rutEmisor']}</td>
  <td>{$row['rutReceptor']}</td>
  <td>{$row['fechaEmision']}</td>
  <td>{$row['dte']}</td>
  <td>{$row['direccion_origen']}<td>
  <td>{$row['monto']}</td>
</tr>
</facturas>
STR;
}
$listado .= '</table>';
```

Comment: lo hice así, en formato xml, pero me da este erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file ya vi las llaves estan todas bien, solo pasa cuando lo hago de esta manera. Si lo hago como estaba antes, no tira errores.

Comment: El fin de las cadenas `STR;` debe estar en la primera columna, sin indentar, sin espacios previos.

Comment: si!! Ya lo arregle, muchas gracias!

Comment: hola, quisiera saber si me puedes sacar de una dua. Cuando genero el xml, lo tengo que hacer en el webservice? Ahí en ese archivo, no en la respuesta.

Comment: Sí, el servidor debe generar el XML, porque el cliente SOAP es lo que espera recibir. Tal vez las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213552/se-puede-enviar-un-json-por-soap-en-php) te pueden ayudar para aclarar tus dudas.

Comment: si, lo leí, gracias!!. Aunque mi duda era mas bien si yo, como programadora, tengo que generar la estructura del xml, en el webservice, ya sea a mano o con alguna función. Ahora lo estoy generando con lo que pusiste ahí pero en vez de STR uso XML. Esta bien así? Esa es mi duda.

Comment: Sí, tu debes generar la estructura y no importa el identificador que uses para _heredoc_. En teoría, puedes crear un _array_ y después generar el XML, según las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml) (en inglés).